# Why is multiprocessing hanging?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing for the first time with the following code:

```
def fuzzy_match(blg_matches, op_matches):
    update_dicts = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        scored_matches = [
            executor.submit(run_matching, blg_match, repeat(op_matches))
            for blg_match in blg_matches
        ]
        for match in concurrent.futures.as_completed(scored_matches):
            update_dicts.append(match)
    return update_dicts
```

However, it just hangs and doesn't do anything.

For testing I've stripped the `run_matching` function down to:

```
def run_matching(blg_match, op_matches):
    return 2
```

And it still hangs.

Both `blg_matches` and `op_matches` are SQLAlchemy Query objects.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is there other code in your example not included here?

Comment: There's plenty more code that's for sure :-) I'm not sure how much use it would be though - it all leads up to generating those two query objects that are the inputs for the ```fuzzy_match``` function. Checked both of them and they're definitely valid query objects.

Comment: It's always possible that code that appears correct or unrelated to the issue is the source of the problem. Please make sure you create a [minimal reproducible example,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can really help.

Comment: It would take a lot of time to produce an MRE - I was thinking there was an obvious answer. Turns out there was... on Windows you have to put the multiprocessing code into ```if __name__ == "__main__":```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there were two issues at play here.

1. I use Windows and you need to make sure your multiprocessing code is in `if __name__ == "__main__":`
2. Multiprocessing doesn't seem to like SQLAlchemy query objects. As soon as I replaced the queries with lists everything worked fine